# IIS Recycle: Argument 'xmlReader' is not valid. A minimum of one .ssdl artifact must be supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

We have an API application running fine for months, but now all of a sudden is causing problems. We have a nightly app pool recycle scheduled at 2AM. Every now and then (but not always) the application crashes after such a recycle, producing this error:

Argument 'xmlReader' is not valid. A minimum of one .ssdl artifact must be supplied.

With this stacktrace

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: ArgumentException 
Exception message: Argument 'xmlReader' is not valid. A minimum of one .ssdl artifact must be supplied. 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadStoreCollection(EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader loader)
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetMetadataWorkspace>b__3()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadAndCheckItemCollection[T](Func`1 itemCollectionLoader)
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace dataSpace, Boolean required)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.TryGetItemCollection(DataSpace dataSpace, ItemCollection& collection)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.IsItemCollectionAlreadyRegistered(DataSpace dataSpace)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(MetadataWorkspace workspace, DbConnection connection, Boolean skipInitialization, Boolean entityConnectionOwnsStoreConnection)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(MetadataWorkspace workspace, DbConnection connection)
at HorekoCore.SingleModelCachingObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String connectionString)
at HorekoCore.Helpers.HorekoEntities..ctor(String connectionString)
at HorekoCore.Utils.get_CurrentEmployeeId()
at HorekoWebApi.WebApiApplication.Application_AuthorizeRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I then do another manual recycle and everything is fine. I already tried some tips to change the //*/ from the connection string to the full name of the SSDL, but that doesn't help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!